# Bootstrap w3school tutorial Dropdown not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm new with bootstrap and I'm trying to create the dropdown bootstrap and its not working.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sample</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="ddButton" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using w3school.com as reference.

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools for anything. The official documentation is far more up to date and accurate: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the console:

```
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4
```

Update **jQuery**

3.x snippet:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2.x snippet:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1.x snippet:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4.
your jquery version is 1.6.2 
so update it to a [recent one.](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

Add **Script  And Css** In Your project . More Information Learn Boostrap DropDown **[W3schools Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**See Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="ddButton" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to include the css for bootstrap. Try this. The path you have included might be wrong. Please verify that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <body>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="ddButton" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>

</html>
```